# How to extract drbd status using grep/regex/cut/awk/sed etc

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, drbd

From my output from /proc/drbd I am trying to extract 'UpToDate/UpToDate' section of this output per device (0 and 1).  I tried:

```
cat /proc/drbd  | grep ' 0:' | grep -Eo 'ds:(.*)'
```

But that gives me:

```
ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
```

That is not what I'm looking for (looking for getting the slot where UpToDate/UpToDate propagates) or basically a return of 'UpToDate/UpToDate'..Anyways, here is the output of /proc/drbd:

```
  0: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
  1: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `grep` command:

```
grep -o 'ds[^[:space:]]\+' /proc/drbd
```

If you don't want the `ds:` in front, you can use grep in `perl` mode (if you have GNU `grep`):

```
grep -oP 'ds:\K[^\s]+' /proc/drbd
```

the `\K` clears everything which has been matched before - in this case `ds:`.

If you don't have GNU `grep`, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{print $8}' /proc/drbd
```

or `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*ds:\([^[:space:]]\+\).*/\1/' /proc/drbd
```

Comment: You are welcome! If you care about portability pick one out of the last two commands

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following commands to query the status of DRBD devices:

```
# drbdadm role <resource>
# drbdadm cstate <resource>
# drbdadm dstate <resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex:

```
grep -o 'ds:([^ ]*)'
```